# Multiplication of 9 with bitwise operator

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Can somebody tell me how to find the table of 9 with using Bit wise operator.A detailed description will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To multiply by 2 to the power of N (i.e. 2^N) shift the bits N times to the left

```
0000 0001 = 1 

times 4 = (2^2 => N = 2) = 2 bit shift : 0000 0100 = 4

times 8 = (2^3 -> N = 3) = 3 bit shift : 0010 0000 = 32
```

etc..

**visualize**

Times 9 just add original value like this

```
0000 1001    // 9 original value

0001 0000    // 2 shift 3 to left
0000 0010 +  // 2
-----------
0001 0010 = 18

0001 1000    // 3(0000 0011) shift 3 to left
0000 0011 +  // 3
-----------
0001 1011 = 27

0010 0000    // 4(0000 0100) shift 3 to left
0000 0100 +  // 4
-----------
0010 0100 = 36
```

etc..

Meaning  x = (n<<3)+n

Shift-and-add multiplication

Answer (score 2):

A bit shift left is like a multiplication of 2. So 2x2x2 = 8 then add the original value again (which is the same as doing +1) = 9

i.e.

```
((v<<1)<<1)<<1) + v == (v << 3) + v
```

Comment: I am asking you multiplication with bit wise operator not a simple mathematical operation.

Comment: he modified before my comment

Comment: It's unnecessary to shift 1 place 3 times. Why not just `(v << 3) + v`?

Comment: It's to demonstrate how it is supposed to work, not to write a program

Comment: @VarunChhangani, you asked how to do a multiplication by 9 with bitwise operators, and that is what it showed above.

Comment: @ Devolus can you write a program because i am facing some problem in my program

Comment: Show the code. The above is basically exactly what you need to write in the code. In real code you can shift directly by 3 as said in the comments above. Just take care about signed and unsigned variables, because this can lead to different results.

Answer (score 0):

9 is 1001<sub>2</sub>, therefore shift left 3 times and add the original value.